# PayPal - Enable In-Context Checkout Experience - What are these?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, paypal, magento2.2.6

I had never enabled the PayPal Checkout Experience before, but thought I would give it a try. Looking at the network, I saw some strange things happening. It looks like PayPal is logging everything. PayPal object are no longer only in the checkout but on every single page. 4 requests per load and it also looks like they're posting back to PayPal on almost every action the user takes.

I do not have PayPal logos or anything allowed anywhere on the site, except the checkout, but then I see, if visiting a product page on the webstite, there are 4 PayPal network calls.

It sure looks like PayPal is taking user analytics from everyone who visits the site. Not really happy about that and not something I ever remember seeing before...

If anyone has any insight onto what is happening, please let me know.

1) is to: https://www.paypal.com/tagmanager/pptm.js?id=

Here is the response header

```
HTTP/2.0 200 OK
server: Apache
x-recruiting: If you are reading this, maybe you should be working at PayPal instead! Check out https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/paypal-jobs
paypal-debug-id: ab0c51038988b
cache-control: max-age=900
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
content-security-policy: default-src 'self' https://*.paypal.com https://*.paypalobjects.com 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'nonce-oqLOISQkruDsl7yW1kcj5CRunx8jfvrR9PzFGIsXoBv/pXkt' 'self' https://*.paypal.com https://*.paypalobjects.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data:; object-src 'none'; font-src 'self' https://*.paypalobjects.com https://*.paypal.com; connect-src 'self' https://*.paypal.com https://*.paypalobjects.com https://nexus.ensighten.com https://*.google-analytics.com 'unsafe-inline'; form-action 'self' https://*.paypal.com; base-uri 'self' https://*.paypal.com; block-all-mixed-content; report-uri https://www.paypal.com/csplog/api/log/csp
etag: W/"216b-Uti7+OyEuwz2tM/OTixB3Km+mCE"
http_x_pp_az_locator: dcg13.slc
paypal-debug-id: ab0c51038988b
content-encoding: gzip
cache-control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
content-type: application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8
dc: slc-b-origin-www-2.paypal.com
content-length: 3130
x-edgeconnect-midmile-rtt: 3
x-edgeconnect-origin-mex-latency: 808
x-edgeconnect-midmile-rtt: 42
x-edgeconnect-origin-mex-latency: 808
x-edgeconnect-midmile-rtt: 12
x-edgeconnect-origin-mex-latency: 808
date: Wed, 26 Sep 2018 17:00:05 GMT
vary: Accept-Encoding
set-cookie: akavpau_ppsd=1537981805~id=f508e748f471853c5de3971544fec45e; Domain=www.paypal.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

The second line bothers me.

Here's the code:

```
!function(e){var a={},t=[{id:"analytics-xo",triggers:[],run:function(e,t){t.track("pageView",{fltp:"analytics",sub_component:"analytics",flag_consume:"yes",subfeature1:"analytics-xo",pageType:t.get("analytics-id"),item:t.get("pptm:containerId"),mrid:t.get("pptm:merchantId"),context:t.get("pptm:context")},{ru:document.referrer})},configuration:{"analytics-id":"REDACTED"}}];!function i(a,u,s){function c(t,e){if(!u[t]){if(!a[t]){var n="function"==typeof require&&require;if(!e&&n)return n(t,!0);if(f)return f(t,!0);var r=new Error("Cannot find module '"+t+"'");throw r.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",r}var o=u[t]={exports:{}};a[t][0].call(o.exports,function(e){return c(a[t][1][e]||e)},o,o.exports,i,a,u,s)}return u[t].exports}for(var f="function"==typeof require&&require,e=0;e<s.length;e++)c(s[e]);return c}({1:[function(e,t,n){var r="function"==typeof Symbol&&"symbol"==typeof Symbol.iterator?function(e){return typeof e}:function(e){return e&&"function"==typeof Symbol&&e.constructor===Symbol&&e!==Symbol.prototype?"symbol":typeof e},o="function"==typeof Symbol&&"symbol"===r(Symbol.iterator)?function(e){return void 0===e?"undefined":r(e)}:function(e){return e&&"function"==typeof Symbol&&e.constructor===Symbol&&e!==Symbol.prototype?"symbol":void 0===e?"undefined":r(e)},i=e("./pptm");"object"===(void 0===a?"undefined":o(a))&&(a=i())},{"./pptm":5}],2:[function(e,t,n){t.exports=function(t){return{url:function(){var e=t.location.href.split("#")[0];return"/"===e[e.length-1]?e.substr(0,e.length-1):e},hostname:function(){return t.location.hostname},path:function(){var e=t.location.pathname;return""===e?"/":"/"===e[e.length-1]?e.substring(0,e.length-1):e}}}},{}],3:[function(e,t,n){var r=e("./request-beacon");t.exports=function(t){return function(e){t=t||"https://www.paypal.com/tagmanager/log","string"==typeof e&&(e={msg:e}),r.send(t,e)}}},{"./request-beacon":6}],4:[function(e,t,n){var r={co:function(e,t){return!!~e.indexOf(t)},nco:function(e,t){return!r.co(e,t)},ew:function(e,t){return new RegExp(t+"$").test(e)},new:function(e,t){return!r.ew(e,t)},eq:function(e,t){return e===t},neq:function(e,t){return!r.eq(e,t)}};t.exports=r},{}],5:[function(e,t,n){var r="function"==typeof Symbol&&"symbol"==typeof Symbol.iterator?function(e){return typeof e}:function(e){return e&&"function"==typeof Symbol&&e.constructor===Symbol&&e!==Symbol.prototype?"symbol":typeof e},o="function"==typeof Symbol&&"symbol"===r(Symbol.iterator)?function(e){return void 0===e?"undefined":r(e)}:function(e){return e&&"function"==typeof Symbol&&e.constructor===Symbol&&e!==Symbol.prototype?"symbol":void 0===e?"undefined":r(e)},p=Object.assign||function(e){for(var t=1;t<arguments.length;t++){var n=arguments[t];for(var r in n)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(n,r)&&(e[r]=n[r])}return e},i=e("./track"),l=e("./log"),g=e("./builtin-variables"),v=e("./trigger-utils"),y=function(e,t){switch(t){case"snippetRun":return!e.snippetRun;default:return!0}},m=function(e){var t=e.paypalDDL,n={event:"snippetRun",t:(new Date).getTime()};if(t){for(var r=!1,o=0;o<t.length;++o)"snippetRun"===t[o].event&&(r=!0);r||t.push(n)}else t=[n];return t},a=function(f){return function(e,t,n,r){if(void 0!==e){f.variables=t||{},f.tags=n||{},f.triggers=r||{},f.unprocessedEvents=[],f.finalDDL={},f.eventListeners={},f.snippetRun=!1;var o,i,a,u="$$page$view";if(f.triggers[u]={id:u,type:"snippetRun"},function(e,t){for(var n in e)e.hasOwnProperty(n)&&(e[n].triggers&&e[n].triggers.length||(e[n].triggers=[t]))}(f.tags,u),f.log=l(f.variables.logServer),f.on=b(e,f),f.builtinVars=g(e),f.shouldTagTrigger=v.createShouldTagTrigger(f.triggers,f.builtinVars),f.processEvents=(o=f,function(e){for(;o.unprocessedEvents.length;){var t=o.unprocessedEvents.shift();if(o.finalDDL=p({},o.finalDDL,t),t.event&&y(o,t.event)&&(v.isKnownTriggerEvent(t.event)?o.triggerTags(t.event):o.triggerTags("customEvent"),e&&o.eventListeners[t.event]))for(var n=0;n<o.eventListeners[t.event].length;++n)o.eventListeners[t.event][n](t)}}),f.triggerTags=(i=e,a=f,function(e){for(var t=0;t<a.tags.length;++t){var n=a.tags[t];if(!d(n))return void a.log({t:"error",msg:"Malformed tag has been prevented from running"});try{a.shouldTagTrigger(n,e)&&n.run(i,h(i,a,n))}catch(e){a.log({t:"error",msg:e.message,stack:e.stack})}}}),void 0!==n){var s=e.paypalDDL=m(e),c=s.push;s.push=function(){for(var e,t=arguments.length,n=Array(t),r=0;r<t;r++)n[r]=arguments[r];return(e=f.unprocessedEvents).push.apply(e,n),f.processEvents(!0),c.apply(s,n)},f.unprocessedEvents.push.apply(f.unprocessedEvents,s.slice(0)),f.processEvents(),f.snippetRun=!0}else f.log("`pptm.init` called with undefined `tags`")}}},d=function(e){return"object"===(void 0===e?"undefined":o(e))&&"string"==typeof e.id&&"function"==typeof e.run&&"object"===o(e.configuration)},u=function(t,n){return function(e){return/^pptm:/.test(e)?t[e.split(":")[1]]:n.configuration[e]}},s=function(e,t){return function(){return t.configuration}},c=function(u){return function(e,t,n){var r,o,i=u.createElement("script");i.type="text/javascript",i.async=!0,i.src=e,r=i,"function"==typeof(o=t)&&(r.addEventListener?r.onload=o:r.onreadystatechange=function(){/(loaded|complete)/.test(r.readyState)&&(r.onreadystatechange=null,o())}),"function"==typeof n&&(i.onerror=n);var a=u.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];a&&a.appendChild(i)}},f=Object.assign||function(e){for(var t=1;t<arguments.length;t++){var n=arguments[t];for(var r in n)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(n,r)&&(e[r]=n[r])}return e},b=function(o,i){return function(e,t){i.eventListeners[e]=i.eventListeners[e]||[],i.eventListeners[e].push(t);for(var n=m(o),r=0;r<n.length;++r)n[r].event===e&&t(n[r])}},h=function(e,t,n){var r={get:u(t.variables,n),getAll:s(t.variables,n),insertExternalScript:c(e.document)};return r.track=i(r.get("pptm:fptiServer")),r.log=t.log,r.on=t.on,r.objectAssign=f,r};t.exports=function(){return{init:a({tags:{},triggers:{},variables:[]})}}},{"./builtin-variables":2,"./log":3,"./track":7,"./trigger-utils":8}],6:[function(e,t,n){t.exports={send:function(e,t){if(e&&t){var n=[];for(var r in t)t.hasOwnProperty(r)&&n.push(encodeURIComponent(r)+"="+encodeURIComponent(t[r]));n=n.join("&"),(new window.Image).src=e+"?"+n}}}},{}],7:[function(e,t,n){var s=Object.assign||function(e){for(var t=1;t<arguments.length;t++){var n=arguments[t];for(var r in n)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(n,r)&&(e[r]=n[r])}return e},c=e("./request-beacon"),f=["pageView","click"];t.exports=function(u){return function(e){var t=1<arguments.length&&void 0!==arguments[1]?arguments[1]:{},n=2<arguments.length&&void 0!==arguments[2]?arguments[2]:{};if(u=u||"https://t.paypal.com/ts",~function(e){for(var t=0;t<f.length;++t)if(f[t]===e)return t;return-1}(e)){var r,o,i=(r=s({identifier:"tagmanagernodeweb",website:"muse",feature:"third-party",s:"ci",subfeature1:"",subfeature2:"",sub_component:"",pageType:"",userType:"",flavor:"",es:"",testVariant:"",link:"",erpg:"",context:{},flag_consume:""},t),s({pgrp:[r.website,r.feature,r.subfeature1,r.subfeature2,r.pageType].join(":"),page:[r.website,r.feature,r.subfeature1,r.subfeature2,r.pageType,r.userType,r.flavor,r.testVariant].join(":"),tsrce:r.identifier,comp:r.identifier,sub_component:r.sub_component,s:r.s,item:r.item,fltp:r.fltp,link:r.link,es:r.flavor,cust:r.cust,mrid:r.mrid,erpg:r.erpg,xe:r.xe,xt:r.xt,qe:r.qe,qt:r.qt,code:r.context.bn_code,partner_name:r.context.partner_name,flag_consume:r.flag_consume},o)),a=s({},i,{e:"pageView"===e?"im":"cl"},"click"===e?{pglk:i.pgrp+"|"+i.link,pgln:i.page+"|"+i.link}:{},{t:(new Date).getTime(),g:(new Date).getTimezoneOffset()},n);c.send(u,function(e){var t={};for(var n in e)e.hasOwnProperty(n)&&(e[n]||!1===e[n]||0===e[n])&&(t[n]=e[n]);return t}(a))}}}},{"./request-beacon":6}],8:[function(e,t,n){var s=e("./operators"),r={snippetRun:!0},c=function(e,t,n){if(!(n.type===t))return!1;var r=n.filters||[];if(!!!r.length)return!0;for(var o=!0,i=0;i<r.length;++i){var a=r[i],u=void 0;switch(a.type){case"BUILT_IN":u=e[a.variable]()}o=o&&s[a.operator](u,a.value)}return o};t.exports={createShouldTagTrigger:function(u,s){return function(e,t){var n=e.triggers;if(!n||!n.length)return!0;for(var r=!1,o=0;o<n.length;++o){var i=u[n[o]],a=c(s,t,i);r=r||a}return r}},isKnownTriggerEvent:function(e){return!!r[e]}}},{"./operators":4}]},{},[1]),"object"==typeof a&&a.init&&a.init(e,{containerIndex:1,containerId:"f983fa75-45ee-4975-b70a-eec0db3d134c",merchantId:"REDACTED",fptiServer:"https://t.paypal.com/ts",logServer:"https://www.paypal.com/tagmanager/log",env:"production",context:{merchant_country:"US"}},t,{})}(window);
```

2) https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/api/logger

```
    access-control-allow-headers    
content-type,x-app-name,x-requested-with
access-control-allow-methods    
POST
access-control-allow-origin 
https://REDACCTED
cache-control   
no-cache
cache-control   
max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
content-encoding    
gzip
content-length  
26
content-security-policy 
default-src 'self' https://*.p….paypal.com/csplog/api/log/csp
content-type    
text/html
date    
Wed, 26 Sep 2018 17:00:06 GMT
dc  
ccg11-origin-www-2.paypal.com
http_x_pp_az_locator    
dcg02.phx
paypal-debug-id 
d483c20eae503
paypal-debug-id 
d483c20eae503
pragma  
no-cache
server  
Apache
set-cookie  
tsrce=hermesnodeweb; Domain=.p…7:00:06 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
set-cookie  
ts=vr%3D16d2d1081660a1e2777d58…0:26:23 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
set-cookie  
nsid=s%3AGfJxVbkN91inpC6lBvOwT…6LE; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure
set-cookie  
X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DLIVE5.WEB.…com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
set-cookie  
X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
set-cookie  
AKDC=ccg11-origin-www-2.paypal… 17:30:06 GMT; path=/; secure
set-cookie  
akavpau_ppsd=1537981806~id=410…com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
strict-transport-security   
max-age=63072000
vary    
Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options  
nosniff
x-cookies   
{"iQCnhIy5-64PvineZIGVfUafYGUg…ghwwFFXoI0G4t5QYBykT_D9ArnS"}
x-cookies-hash  
7d01bd5db15145c3d880d772eb1884…f903be44802f56e9cc0f3d967d0bc
x-edgeconnect-midmile-rtt   
78
x-edgeconnect-origin-mex-latency    
140
X-Firefox-Spdy  
h2
x-powered-by    
Express
x-recruiting    
If you are reading this, maybe…com/us/webapps/mpp/paypal-jobs
x-xss-protection    
1; mode=block
```

3) https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/api/logger

This is a 2 part with both a GET and POST

```
Request URL:https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/api/logger
Request method:POST
Remote address:23.54.148.230:443

cache-control: no-cache, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 26
content-security-policy: default-src 'self' https://*.paypal.com https://*.paypalobjects.com 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src 'self' https://*.paypal.com https://*.paypalobjects.com https://nexus.ensighten.com https://connect.facebook.net https://www.facebook.com https://m.facebook.com; frame-src 'self' https://*.paypal.com https://*.paypalobjects.com https://*.cardinalcommerce.com https://staticxx.facebook.com https://www.facebook.com https://m.facebook.com https://*.baidu.com https://*.baifubao.com; script-src 'self' https://*.paypal.com https://*.paypalobjects.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src https: data:; base-uri 'self' https://*.paypal.com; object-src 'none'; block-all-mixed-content; report-uri https://www.paypal.com/csplog/api/log/csp
content-type: text/html
date: Wed, 26 Sep 2018 16:44:55 GMT
dc: ccg11-origin-www-1.paypal.com
http_x_pp_az_locator: dcg01.phx
paypal-debug-id: 666d9800d71d9, 666d9800d71d9
pragma: no-cache
server: Apache
status: 200
strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-edgeconnect-midmile-rtt: 76
x-edgeconnect-origin-mex-latency: 151
x-powered-by: Express
x-recruiting: If you are reading this, maybe you should be working at PayPal instead! Check out https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/paypal-jobs
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

With the Params as

```
events  […]
0   {…}
event   ppxo_setup_production
level   info
payload {…}
country US
env production
host    www.hbcsurf.com
lang    en
pageID  b723d6dff8
path    /REDACTED.html
prev_corr_ids   
referer www.REDACTED.com
timestamp   1537981201845
uid 61c68b9504_ge3dunjzhizds
ver 4.0.221
windowID    a52af05228
1   {…}
event   ppxo_current_protocol_https
level   debug
payload {…}
country US
env production
host    www.REDACTED.com
lang    en
pageID  b723d6dff8
path    /REDACTED.html
prev_corr_ids   
referer www.REDACTED.com
timestamp   1537981201846
uid 61c68b9504_ge3dunjzhizds
ver 4.0.221
windowID    a52af05228
2   {…}
event   ppxo_current_script_protocol_https
level   debug
payload {…}
country US
env production
host    www.REDACTED.com
lang    en
pageID  b723d6dff8
path    /REDACTED.html
prev_corr_ids   
referer www.REDACTED.com
timestamp   1537981201853
uid 61c68b9504_ge3dunjzhizds
ver 4.0.221
windowID    a52af05228
3   {…}
event   ppxo_current_script_protocol_match
level   debug
payload {…}
country US
env production
host    www.REDACTED.com
lang    en
pageID  b723d6dff8
path    /REDACTED.html
prev_corr_ids   
referer www.REDACTED.com
timestamp   1537981201854
uid 61c68b9504_ge3dunjzhizds
ver 4.0.221
windowID    a52af05228
4   {…}
event   ppxo_current_script_version_4_0_221
level   debug
payload {…}
country US
env production
host    www.REDACTED.com
lang    en
pageID  b723d6dff8
path    /REDACTED.html
prev_corr_ids   
referer www.REDACTED.com
timestamp   1537981201854
uid 61c68b9504_ge3dunjzhizds
ver 4.0.221
windowID    a52af05228
5   {…}
event   ppxo_current_script_time
level   debug
payload {…}
country US
env production
host    www.REDACTED.com
lang    en
loadTime    131
pageID  b723d6dff8
path    /oneill-mutant-4-3.html
prev_corr_ids   
referer www.REDACTED.com
timestamp   1537981201854
uid 61c68b9504_ge3dunjzhizds
ver 4.0.221
windowID    a52af05228
6   {…}
event   ppxo_current_script_time_0
level   debug
payload {…}
country US
env production
host    www.REDACTED.com
lang    en
pageID  b723d6dff8
path    /REDACTED.html
prev_corr_ids   
referer www.REDACTED.com
timestamp   1537981201855
uid 61c68b9504_ge3dunjzhizds
ver 4.0.221
windowID    a52af05228
7   {…}
event   ppxo_paypal_legacy_setup
level   info
payload {…}
country US
env production
host    www.REDACTED.com
id  Y9AVFUQHCSK4L
lang    en
options {"checkoutInited":false,"click":"<function>","locale":"en_US","environment":"production","button":["paypal-express-in-context-checkout-main"]}
pageID  b723d6dff8
path    /REDACTED.html
prev_corr_ids   
referer www.REDACTED.com
timestamp   1537981202642
uid 61c68b9504_ge3dunjzhizds
ver 4.0.221
windowID    a52af05228
8   {…}
event   ppxo_post_bridge_not_required
level   debug
payload {…}
country US
env production
host    www.REDACTED.com
lang    en
pageID  b723d6dff8
path    /REDACTED.html
prev_corr_ids   
referer www.REDACTED.com
timestamp   1537981202646
uid 61c68b9504_ge3dunjzhizds
ver 4.0.221
windowID    a52af05228
9   {…}
event   ppxo_paypal_legacy_render_custom_button
level   info
payload {…}
country US
env production
host    www.REDACTED.com
lang    en
pageID  b723d6dff8
path    /REDACTED.html
prev_corr_ids   
referer www.REDACTED.com
timestamp   1537981202647
uid 61c68b9504_ge3dunjzhizds
ver 4.0.221
windowID    a52af05228
meta    {…}
state   ui_init
tracking    […]
0   {…}
checkoutjs_version  4.0.221
feed_name   checkoutjs
page_session_id 61c68b9504_ge3dunjzhizds
referer_url www.REDACTED.com
seller_id   
serverside_data_source  checkout
state_name  checkoutjs_pptm
transition_name process_pptm_load
1   {…}
checkoutjs_version  4.0.221
feed_name   checkoutjs
page_session_id 61c68b9504_ge3dunjzhizds
referer_url www.hbcsurf.com
seller_id   
serverside_data_source  checkout
state_name  checkoutjs_load
transition_name process_script_load
transition_time 131
2   {…}
checkoutjs_version  4.0.221
feed_name   checkoutjs
page_session_id 61c68b9504_ge3dunjzhizds
referer_url www.REDACTED.com
seller_id   
serverside_data_source  checkout
state_name  checkoutjs_pptm
transition_name process_pptm_loaded
3   {…}
button_type custom
checkoutjs_version  4.0.221
feed_name   checkoutjs
page_session_id 61c68b9504_ge3dunjzhizds
referer_url www.REDACTED.com
seller_id   
serverside_data_source  checkout
state_name  checkoutjs_load
transition_name process_button_render
```

Not 100% sure what's happening, but it looks like every time I move my mouse on the page - same page, switching tabs or any mouse activity, including frame losing focus, something happens with the 3rd party PayPal tracker/logger.

Anyone with more knowledge know if this is indeed a mouse tracker?